# Wordpress stripping <style> tags from document

Tags: html, css, wordpress

If I use the Wordpress text editor and put  tags into the html, when it renders, it displays the literal code inside the style tags. This seems to be because Wordpress will strip out the style tags - I  can see them being removed/stripped out as soon as I click update. Does anyone know why the style tags are being stripped out of the document after it gets processed by Wordpress?

**This is happening when I use the following editor view:**

[image]

**The style tag is stripped so then we get literal text:**

[image]

Comment: That's invalid HTML regardless. You can't use `<style>`-tags inside HTML-content. Just append the style as attributes to the tags, instead. Or write some CSS that you can use by adding a class or similar to the element.

Comment: Huh I didn't know you couldn't do that

Answer (score 3):

The WordPress tinymce stripe out some tag inlcuding style tag.

You can add support for style tag.

Add the following code in `functions.php`

```
add_filter('tiny_mce_before_init', 'prefix_filter_tiny_mce_before_init');
function prefix_filter_tiny_mce_before_init( $options ) {

    if ( ! isset( $options['extended_valid_elements'] ) ) {
        $options['extended_valid_elements'] = 'style';
    } else {
        $options['extended_valid_elements'] .= ',style';
    }

    if ( ! isset( $options['valid_children'] ) ) {
        $options['valid_children'] = '+body[style]';
    } else {
        $options['valid_children'] .= ',+body[style]';
    }

    if ( ! isset( $options['custom_elements'] ) ) {
        $options['custom_elements'] = 'style';
    } else {
        $options['custom_elements'] .= ',style';
    }

    return $options;
}
```